# Is it possible to use django-cryptography with filter or get methods?

Tags: python, django, python-cryptography

we are trying to encrypt some fields in Django models, so that no one get data through database access (previously we used django.core.signing), but we need it in some queries where we need to query based on the value but we are getting this error

*** django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup'exact' for EncryptedCharField or join on the field not permitted.

using Django 2.1 and 
django-cryptography 0.3